# Postgresql 10.x how to configure Master - Master replication

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, multi-master-replication

I need to configure Master - Master Postgresql replication servers. I guess psql 10 or 11 will be used for this.

But I can`t find any information about master-master configuration, only master-slave.

Here is a quick example for logical replication setup:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/logical-replication-quick-setup.html

Final steps are:

- CREATE PUBLICATION ...
- CREATE SUBSCRIPTION ...

This example looks like master - slave example - one DB instance will "send" data and the second - "receive".

What steps should be for master - master replica? Does anybody have any examples of working configuration?

Comment: No, there is no built-in master-master replication in Postgres. Why do you think you need that?

Comment: I`m just trying to help set up this configuration

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/different-replication-solutions.html
If I correctly understand it - "Allows multiple master servers" is for "built-in logical replication, pglogical"

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, Is there any roadmap plan for built-in master-master replication in Postgres in future versions 13 / 14 ?

Comment: As far as I know, since PostgreSQL 10.x you can setup logical replication so that every master creates publication and every master subscribes from every other master. Haven't tried it in real world, though. DDL will not be replicated so any database schema change is going to be major pain.